Why must a constraint force be normal?
If we impose that a particle follows a holonomic constraint, so that it always remains on a surface defined by some function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=0$ with $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we get a condition on it's acceleration normal to the surface.
First we can get a condition on the normal velocity:
since $f(\vec{x})=0 \; \forall t$
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(\vec{x(t)})=0$$
$$\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \dot{\vec{x(t)}}=0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i} \dot{\vec{x(t)_i}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0$$
Thus the velocity normal to the surface must at all times be 0.
We can derive this again to get a condition on the normal acceleration.
$$\sum_{i} \ddot{\vec{x(t)}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} + \sum_{i,j} \dot{x_i}\dot{x_j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=0$$
$$\sum_{i} \ddot{\vec{x(t)}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=-\sum_{i,j} \dot{x_i}\dot{x_j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
This left side is equivalent to the acceleration normal to the surface.
$$\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \ddot{\vec{x(t)}}=-\sum_{i,j} \dot{x_i}\dot{x_j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
If we cobine this with Newton's second axiom, assuming that on the body there is some general force $\vec{F}$ and a force costraining the movment of the particle to take place on this surface $\vec{F_C}$, we get:
$$\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \ddot{\vec{x(t)}}=\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \frac{1}{m}(\vec{F}+\vec{F_C})$$
Plugging this back in:
$$\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \frac{1}{m}(\vec{F}+\vec{F_C})=-\sum_{i,j} \dot{\vec{x_i}}\dot{\vec{x_j}}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
$$\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \vec{F_C}=-m\sum_{i,j} \dot{\vec{x_i}}\dot{\vec{x_j}}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}+\nabla f |_{\vec{x(t)}} \cdot \vec{F}$$
This the general condition on the normal component of $\vec{F_C}$
What kind of equation is this? Does it have any relevance in explaining why it is better to assume that the coercive force only has a normal component? Perhaps the equation simplifies in some important way?

A force that constrains an object to stay on a surface does not have to be normal. But it sometimes is.
As an example, consider ice. An object cannot penetrate the ice. Ice exerts a normal force to prevent that. It does not exert a tangential force.
By contrast, a sidewalk exerts both a normal force and a tangential friction force.

But the friction force is not a constraining force. It's a separate effect, and plays no part in keeping the object on the surface.

@vercassivlauno On a sloping surface friction plays a role in keeping the object 'located' on the surface.

Because tangential forces would usually violate conversation of energy. If $\dot{\vec v}\cdot \vec v=0$, then $\vert \vec v\vert^2$ and thus energy remains constant. This is because $|\vec v|^2=\vec v\cdot \vec v$ and thus $\frac{d}{dt}|\vec v|^2=2\dot{\vec v}\cdot\vec v=0$, making $|\vec v|^2$ constant if acceleration is perpendicular to velocity. And since velocity can be any vector tangential to the constraint surface, the only possible way for acceleration to be perpendicular to velocity is to either:

Have it be normal to the whole surface
Have it depend on the velocity

The former are much easier to treat and are the focus of usual mechanics courses.

But doesn't the way I have very generally derived the condition for the normal component of a force which costrains a particle on a surface include velocity terms?
